# Check a status of training process in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, caret

I'm training a model using `caret` package in R for almost 3 days. The calculations are running in parallel (multiple processes). Unfortunately there is no output in R console (SVM model from `kernlab` package) so I don't know if I'm 10% or 90% done.

**Is there a way to figure out somehow what is the process of the calculations?**

I'm using OS X so maybe dumping the process stack and trying to find parameters values currently being evaluated or iteration of k-fold. But how?

EDIT: the script for training:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, selectionFunction = "best", 
                     classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction =  twoClassSummary,
                     verboseIter = TRUE)

grid_svm <- expand.grid(.C = logseq(2^-15, 2^3, 10))

svm <- train(CLASS ~ ., data = dataset, method = "svmLinear", preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
            metric = "ROC", trControl = ctrl, tuneGrid = grid_svm, verbose = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 10):

When using `caret` for training, you can set the option `verbose = TRUE` within the `train` function.  For further detail, there is also the `verboseIter` argument within the `trainControl` call.  Max Kuhn has a great website built from the github page that can help you familiarize yourself more with the functions [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know about those options but they don't seem to work for parallel processing. I have updated my post with a snippet of the used code.

Comment: Ah, that was unclear (your snippet omits the `allowParallel` argument however).  As of now, I am unaware of any functionality within caret to provide parallel verbose output. This is because the `foreach` loops have `verbose` hard coded as `FALSE`.  If this is important to you, your best bet may be to submit an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/topepo/caret) and see if a change can be implemented.

Comment: Following your recommendation I have created an issue on Github. I think that it's quite desired functionality.

Comment: Good, as a courtesy if the functionality is created it would be great if you could re-post here with the answer so others can see how the solution works.

Comment: You can modify the `fit` function to print out more. If you are not seeing any logs and you have `verboseIter = TRUE`, are you using RStudio? RStudio diverts output differently than R; I get logs in base R but not in RStudio. There's also `top` on unix so you can check to make sure you have not exhausted system memory (you need more to run in parallel) and that the workers are active.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610593/r-package-caret-print-iteration-when-using-parallel